# codeigniter form using ajax jquery and json encode

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to make a contact form, using ajax and jquery, I am returning the validation errors using json encode, when I try to display the errors as an alert box, all it says in the alert box is undefined.

form

```
 <?php echo form_open('page/contact_validation',array('class'=> 'contact_form'));?>
<div class="row">

    <div class="large-6 columns large-centered">
        <div class="row">

          <div class="medium-12 columns">

            <label>Name
              <input type="text"placeholder="Enter Name" name="name"id="name">
            </label>

             <div class="jsError_name"></div>
          </div><!--medium 12-->
        </div><!--row-->
               <div class="row">

          <div class="medium-12 columns">

            <label>Email
              <input type="text"placeholder="Enter Email"name="email" id="email">
            </label>
            <div class="jsError_email"></div>
          </div><!--medium 12-->
        </div><!--row-->
        <div class="row">

          <div class="medium-12 columns">

            <label>Phone Number
              <input type="text"placeholder="Enter Number">
            </label>
          </div><!--medium 12-->
        </div><!--row-->
         <div class="row">

          <div class="medium-12 columns">

            <label>Message
              <input type="text"placeholder="Message">
            </label>
          </div><!--medium 12-->
        </div><!--row-->
        <div class="row column">
          <button type="submit" class="button" value="Send"id="submit">
          <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fi-mail"></i></span>
          Send</button>
          <button class="button reset"type="reset"value="reset">Reset</button>

        </div>
    </div>


  </div><!--row-->
  <?php echo form_close();?>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$('form.contact_form').on('submit',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$.post('contact_validation', $('form.contact_form').serialize(), function(data) {

alert(data.firstvalue);


      });
    });
});
```

contact validation function

```
   public function contact_validation() {

      $formRules =array(

        array(
              'field' =>'name',
              'rules' => 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[30]'

          ),
        array(
              'field' =>'email',
              'rules' => 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[30]'

          )

        );

      $this->form_validation->set_rules($formRules);

      if($this->form_validation->run()== true) {
        echo 'success';
      } else {


      echo json_encode(array('firstvalue' => form_error('name'),'secondvalue' => form_error('email')));
      }
   }



}
```

Comment: if you `alert(JSON.stringify(data));` does it print anything?

Comment: To troubleshoot ajax requests go to the network tab of your browser console (F12) and click on the request name in the list to get the details. There you can even see PHP errors.